# Display a String after specific character

Tags: sql-server

Consider A string has multiple dots but I want to read and display from 5th dot(.) to end of the string.Any single select query can you suggest.
Eg:
**I/P**

```
We.are.inserting.a.lot.of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.
```

**o/P**

```
of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `CHARINDEX`, one method:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(500);
SET @String = 'We.are.inserting.a.lot.of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.';

SELECT STUFF(@string, 1, CI5.CI,'')
FROM (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',@String))) CI1(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',@String, CI1.CI+1))) CI2(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',@String, CI2.CI+1))) CI3(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',@String, CI3.CI+1))) CI4(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('.',@String, CI4.CI+1))) CI5(CI);
```

Returns: `'of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.'`

Comment: @AryanDas `CI` is the alias for the column in the `CROSS APPLY`.  The prior alias (I.E. `CI1`) is the alias of the dataset from the `CROSS APPLY`. Each new `APPLY` gets the location of the next `.` and then the front of the string is stripped off using `STUFF`.

Comment: I tested this. It seems to have the same performance as the nested solution as a one-liner

Comment: Nested Solution @t-clausen.dk ?

Comment: it is there now. It has the same syntax as yours, but without the CROSS APPLY. I figured nesting would be faster. But it seems to be a tiny bit slower

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes, the queries will effectively be synonymous. It's more a readability thing (using `CROSS APPLY`), as nested functions can become quite difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a recursice CTE for rescue:

```
DECLARE @yourString NVARCHAR(MAX)='We.are.inserting.a.lot.of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.';
DECLARE @CountDots INT=5;

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT @yourString AS Original
          ,CHARINDEX('.',@yourString) AS PosDot
          ,1 AS DotCount
    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.Original
          ,CHARINDEX('.',@yourString,r.PosDot+1)
          ,r.DotCount+1
    FROM recCTE AS r
    WHERE r.DotCount<@CountDots
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourString,(SELECT MAX(PosDot) FROM recCTE)+1,LEN(@yourString))
```

One advantage is that you can define the count of dots dynamically. Another advantage is that you can fully inline this to any query, VIEW or iTVF.

### UPDATE: Set-based approach

```
DECLARE @yourStringTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @yourStringTable VALUES 
 ('We.are.inserting.a.lot.of.records by using SSIS Package.even.the.records are.not committed.')
,('1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8');
DECLARE @CountDots INT=5;

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,SomeString AS Original
          ,CHARINDEX('.',SomeString) AS PosDot
          ,1 AS DotCount
    FROM @yourStringTable
    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.ID
          ,r.Original
          ,CHARINDEX('.',r.Original,r.PosDot+1)
          ,r.DotCount+1
    FROM recCTE AS r
    WHERE r.DotCount<@CountDots
)
SELECT ID
      ,Original
      ,SUBSTRING(Original,(SELECT MAX(x.posDot) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.ID=recCTE.ID)+1,LEN(Original))
FROM recCTE
WHERE PosDot=(SELECT MAX(x.posDot) FROM recCTE AS x WHERE x.ID=recCTE.ID)
```

Comment: thanks .. I wanted this kind of query using recursive CTE. (Y)

Comment: The disadvantage with this solution, is that you can't use this directly in the query when selecting from a table without spaghetti code . In this case you need this as a function. The function will result in a recursive call for every row and get a bad performance. The advantage is that you can reuse the function and change the requirement for number of dot. Or even change to a different character as split parameter

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I like your nested approach, but it is limited to a pre-known count... See my update for a - quite readable - set-based approach

Answer (score 1):

Nesting the CHARINDEX:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(val,1, charindex('.',val,charindex('.',val,charindex('.',val,charindex('.',
   val,charindex('.',val)+1)+1)+1)+1), '')
FROM (values('.2.3.4.5.6.7'),('2.3.4.5.6.7'),('abc')) x(val)
```

This will return the whole string, when the string doesn't contain 5 dots.

Answer (score 0):

For the said string values only `patindex()` function would be sufficient to read string after few `dot(.)s` with `substring()` function

```
select 
        substring(I/P, patindex('%[.A-Z].[A-Z][.A-Z].[A-Z]%', I/P)+2, LEN(I/P)) [O/P]
from table
```

Comment: it is not workig @yogesh.. can you pls check your query